# How to add a C# class to an F# project

Tags: c#, f#

How do you add a C# (not static) class to an F# projec? i have tried: open namespace, i ve also tried locating the classes DLL but with no luck.

I have added the C# class to the F#'s project folder and included the file.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The most common way is to have separate C# and F# projects in your solution. Then you can reference the C# project from the F# project, which allows you to use the `public` types from the C# project in your F# project.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference either the project or the dll in the project. You can't have both a C# file and a F# file in the same project.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix .NET languages in a single project.

This is a limitation of the .NET tooling and compilers.

One option is to add a C# project with the C# class and reference this project in your F# project.

Another option is to build a C# project into a DLL and reference the DLL directly (saving on compilation time).

Comment: Are you sure about the compilation time? Commonly, build systems that handle interdependent projects only rebuild projects that (or one of whose dependencies) have actually changed, and unless I'm mistaken, MSBuild generally does that whenever I build one of my multi-project solutions.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I was thinking about "rebuild all"